# Why there is no file in config folder in my laravel project? How can I change the configuration of my laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to change the configuration of a laravel project, but I can't find any files in the config folder. I don't remember which artisan commands were executed, like `cache`、`clear`、`dump`, and there is only one file named packages.php in the bootstrap/cache folder, so how can I find the configuration files, and change the configuration?

Comment: they are in the `config` folder in the root of your application

Comment: I think it may be deleted by yourself by mistake. There is no any artisan command which will cause deletion of config files